# action script moving movieclips separately

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've write a actionscript 3.0 code, I have a background movie clip and  and a simple space ship movie clip. I want to move spaceship right when left arrow button is pushed.To do that I've write the following code:

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    public class main extends MovieClip{
        public function main(){

         var bground_mc:backGround_mc=new backGround_mc();
         bground_mc.x=0;
         bground_mc.y=0;
         bground_mc.height=400;
         bground_mc.width=550;
         addChild(bground_mc);       


         var myHero:Ship=new Ship();
         addChild(myHero);
        // setChildIndex(myHero,numChildren - 1);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressedDown);
        }

        function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if (event.keyCode == 37){
                x+=50;
                            // myHero.x+=50; according to me, It should be like this???
            }
            else{
                trace("non left arrow key is pushed");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my first view of screen:

http://prntscr.com/2pkwga

When I push the left arow button, not only space ship but also background moves through right. How could I solve my problem ?

After one push to left arrow :

http://prntscr.com/2pkwxn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `x+=50;` in this case refers to whole main class. If you just want to move just a space ship you should change 'myHero' property.

So:
`myHero.x += 50;`

**EDIT**

Sorry, `myHero` is local variable in constructor so it's not accessible from outside.

Do:

`private var myHero:Ship;`

just before the constructor and inside just change it to

`myHero = new Ship();`

Comment: thanks for reply , but If I write myHero.x+=50; I get the following error: 1120: Access of undefined property myHero. @3vilguy

Comment: If I write myHero.x+=50;  into somewhere in public function main(), it does not cause any problem, but I have to write it into function keyPressedDown and when I write it, I get the error mentioned above @3vilguy